# Need to know Zend Framework 1 exact version

Tags: zend-framework, version

I have a Zend Framework 1 project .How can I find out, which ZF1 version is currently being used?

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Version.php

Comment: i have tried this line of code echo Zend_Version::getLatest();  Getting below error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Version::getLatest() in C:\wamp\www\dev\application\views\scripts\user\dashboard.phtml on line 5

Comment: Check do you have that file first and maybe, method name is changed. Find in your project file called `Version.php`.

Comment: yup i found it :) there i found const VERSION = '1.10.3'; This is what i was looking for . Thanks !

Comment: Consider adding this as an answer and accepting it

Comment: from where i can accept this answer, unable to see any option to accept answer.